# How can I stop these inline elements overflowing the div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a solid border. Within this div are multiple 'tags', which should all be contained within the border of the div. I've used the following code to do this:

```css
.sidebox {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#tag {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebox">
  <h2>Popular Tags</h2>
  <a href="" id="tag">Tag 1</a><a href="" id="tag">Tag 2</a><a href="" id="tag">Tag 3</a><a href="" id="tag">Tag 4</a><a href="" id="tag">Tag 5</a><a href="" id="tag">Tag 6</a><a href="" id="tag">Tag 7</a><a href="" id="tag">Tag 8</a>
</div>
```

The problem is that these tags overflow the div. There are displayed as one long line of tags. How can I make tags go down to the next line within the div, rather than overflow it?

I've tried using `overflow: none;` but this causes them all to overlap each other.

Comment: Have you tried using white-space: normal; in the sidebox div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Display them as `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Also, you should use a `class` instead of `ID` for each `tag`. You have to use `ID` when the elements are **unique**. You have to use a `class` when you want to use a property in more than one element.

```css
.sidebox{
    border-style: solid; 
    width: 250px; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.tag {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebox">
     <h2>Popular Tags</h2>
     <a href="" class="tag">Tag 1</a><a href="" class="tag">Tag 2</a><a href="" class="tag">Tag 3</a><a href="" class="tag">Tag 4</a><a href="" class="tag">Tag 5</a><a href="" class="tag">Tag 6</a><a href="" class="tag">Tag 7</a><a href="" class="tag">Tag 8</a>
   </div>
```